# Store fetched Image to Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I have an image file extracted from a url by using urlfetch api of python google app engine.

```
img = urlfetch.fetch(url).content
```

I want to upload it to the blobstore in order to be able to serve it to the users. Hence, I'll be willing to save the blob_key to the datastore. As given in the documentations of Google App Engine Blobstore, I do not want to make a upload page for the user as this work is to be done on the server side.

What should be the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE With the arrival of app engine 1.9.0 an application can use the default GCS bucket, which provides an already configured bucket with FREE QUOTA!**

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate#Using_the_Default_GCS_Bucket)

You can also send a multi-part form to a blobstore upload_url.

This is my code to upload a blob to the blobstore:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import webapp2
import mimetypes
import logging
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import blobstore                                                      
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.runtime import DeadlineExceededError

CRLF = b'\r\n'
BOUNDERY = b'--Th15-Is-ThE-BoUnDeRy--'


def _encode_multipart(_fields=None, _files=None):
    """ Generator inserts fields and files to create a multipart payload """

    for (field_name, field_value) in _fields or []:
        yield b'--' + BOUNDERY + CRLF
        yield b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % str(field_name) + CRLF
        yield CRLF
        yield str(field_value) + CRLF

    for (file_name, file_data) in _files or []:
        yield b'--' + BOUNDERY + CRLF
        yield b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"' \
              % str(file_name) + CRLF
        yield b'Content-Type: %s' % mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0] + CRLF
        yield CRLF
        yield file_data + CRLF

    yield b'--%s--' % BOUNDERY + CRLF


def create_upload_url(for_url):

    return blobstore.create_upload_url(for_url, max_bytes_per_blob=1048576)


def _fetch_blob_update(payload):

    upload_url = create_upload_url(webapp2.uri_for('blob_update', _full=True))
    try:
        response = urlfetch.fetch(
            url=upload_url,
            payload=payload,
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            deadline=40,
            follow_redirects=False,
            headers={b'Content-Type': str('multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDERY)}
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            logging.error('URL : %s fetch ERROR : %d' % (upload_url, response.status_code))
            return None
        else:
            return response.content
    except (urlfetch.DownloadError, DeadlineExceededError), e:
        logging.error('fetch %s download or deadline error, exception : %s'
                      % (upload_url, str(e)))
        return None


def blob_update_by_upload(ndb_key, blob):
    """ update blob using upload to the blobstore """

    result = _fetch_blob_update(b''.join(_encode_multipart(_files=[(ndb_key.id(), blob)])))
    return blobstore.BlobKey(result)


class BlobUpdate(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    """ has named route : blob_update """

    def post(self):
        """ blob upload handler returns the new blobkey """

        blob_info = self.get_uploads('file')[0]
        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = b'text/plain'
        self.response.write(str(blob_info.key()))
```

Route:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/blob_update', handler='....BlobUpdate', name='blob_update')
```

Answer (score 2):

The fileapi for blobstore has been deprecated, so you'll need to upload to cloud storage instead of blobstore.

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

filename = "<your bucket + filename>"   
with gcs.open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(img)
blobstore_filename = "/gs"+filename
#this is needed if you want to continue using blob_keys.
return blobstore.BlobKey(blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename))
```

See the docs for gcs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)